# C++ Could not match `Container<typename Container::value_type>`

Tags: c++, templates

The below `serialize` function doesn't match with the call.
The serialize function should match a pair that contains a `std::string` and an iterable type that has a parameter.

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>


namespace S
{
typedef int Error;

typedef std::string Json;

std::variant<Json, Error> serialize(std::pair<std::string, int> entry)
{
    return std::to_string(entry.second);
}

template <template <typename> typename Container>
std::variant<Json, Error> serialize(std::pair<std::string, Container<typename Container::value_type>> entry)
{
    return Json();
}
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3 };
    S::serialize<std::vector<int>>(std::pair<std::string, std::vector<int>>{ "a", v });
    return 0;
}
```

The error is `error C2672: 'S::serialize': no matching overloaded function found`

Any idea why? What would an workaround look like?

Comment: Why do you use template template? `template <typename Container>` with `std::pair<std::string, Container>` as argument works fine: https://godbolt.org/z/hvKTs8nsb

Comment: `Container` is a template template argument. `std::vector<int>` is not a template, its a type

Comment: @Yksisarvinen because I want the template to match  an iterable type that has a parameter(as mentioned), I don't want it to match other types for which I have other specializations.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I don't understand what you mean, could you elaborate?

Comment: `std::vector` is the template, `std::vector<int>` is not a template, it is a type. Now this: `template <template <typename> typename Container>` declares `Container` to be a template template argument. An instantiation of the function template would be eg `serialize<std::vector>` (but number of arguments does not match)

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "an iterable type that has a parameter." ? You want anything that has `begin` and `end` ? Note that `std::vector` has 2 template arguments, though not sure if thats what you mean with "has a parameter"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I understand now what you mean, I was trying to avoid using concepts to check that the type has an `end`/`begin` which is indeed what I am looking for.

Comment: why do you try to avoid using concepts? The alternative is SFINAE, which is way more complicated. What you have now in the code is not the way to go.

Comment: I was trying to use just the template template definition, but I now understand that it only works for fixed container types like `Container<int>`. Yes, concepts are preferable to SFINAE.

Comment: Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Pc8vMGsKW

Comment: `Container` is a template template, so the correct argument type would be `std::vector` not `std::vector<int>`. That is, you pass the template without arguments, not the fully specified class. And knowing that, what is the value of `Container::value_type` supposed to be? It sounds like you just want a normal type template argument. You don't need a template template to pass a fully specified class template. You only need them when you pass a template whose arguments aren't specified by the user, when you want to pass the template and let the function pass its own arguments for the template.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes, the solution would be to use a simple template along with a concept, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is common mistake to pack in template function parameters to many details about requirement.

Make your template more general then use SFINAE to limit given template parameter.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = typename T::value_type>
std::variant<Json, Error> serialize(const std::pair<std::string, T>& entry)
{
    (void)entry;
    return Json();
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hE38na317).

Now your attempt:

```cpp
template <template <typename> typename Container>
std::variant<Json, Error> serialize(std::pair<std::string, Container<typename Container::value_type>> entry)
```

Note you are trying explain that `Container` template depends on itself `Container<typename Container::value_type>>`. This self reference is like Russell's paradox.
Even assuming this is a good approach formally this should look like:

```cpp
template <template <typename> typename Container>
std::variant<Json, Error> serialize(std::pair<std::string, Container<typename Container<typename Container< .... >::value_type>>::value_type>> entry)
```

After all `Container` is template template parameter, so to use it as a type it needs template parameter.